# Performing actions on form1 from form2

Tags: vb.net, winforms, libvlcsharp

I have this sub on form1:

```
  Public Sub PlayMaskVideo(filePath As String)
      If File.Exists(filePath) Then
          If MaterialTabControl2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then Mask0Img.Visible = False

          If libVLC Is Nothing Then
              Core.Initialize()
              libVLC = New LibVLC()
          End If

          mediaPlayer = New MediaPlayer(libVLC)
          Mask0VLC.MediaPlayer = mediaPlayer

          media = New Media(libVLC, filePath, FromType.FromPath)
          media.AddOption("input-repeat=65535")
          mediaPlayer.Volume = 0
          mediaPlayer.Play(media)
      End If
  End Sub
```

This code works as expected if called on Form1, it plays a video in the vlcsharp player on the form.

What I'm trying to do is call it from form2 like this:

```
Form1.PlayMaskVideo(outputPreview)
```

I'm expecting the video to play in the form1 video player however nothing happens. I thought maybe its an issue with vlcsharp, but even this line doesn't execute:

```
If MaterialTabControl2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then Mask0Img.Visible = False
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: "Form1.PlayMaskVideo(outputPreview)" <- is 'Form1' the name of your form, or the name of an instance of your form? Possibly you're falling foul of the default instance in vb.

Comment: Yep, its called Form1. I also just tried removing the FileExists condition and still no go.

Comment: But do you instantiate an instance of the form before calling the method? Or just call it like your code shows? You need to "dim f as new Form1" -> "f.PlayNaskVideo..."

Comment: So I changed the code to this:
        'Dim f1 As New Form1
        f1.PlayMaskVideo(outputPreview)'.

Still not working, I'd think at least this line should fire?

'If MaterialTabControl2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then Mask0Img.Visible = False'

What is strange is that I put a msgbox("test") in the PlayMaskVideo(outputPreview) sub and that DID fire. it just seems like the controls are inaccessable?

Comment: The code you have showed is referring to the default instance of Form1. If the instance already displayed is not the default instance then you're not referring to that form object, so you won't see anything happen in that form object. If you call the method on a different object that you can't see, that's why you won't see anything happen. If you actually debug your code, you'll likely see that the code is executed but in a different instance of Form1. You can identify the instance using a random number assigned to a field.

Comment: Having said that, if Form1 is your startup form then it should be the default instance, so maybe it's some other issue. This is why you need to debug your code first, before asking a question. If you don't know how to debug, stop what you're doing and learn now.

Comment: Default instances are a way for new VB.NET developers, especially those coming from VB6, to "cheat" and ignore OO principles where forms are concerned. They really shouldn't be used anyway. I'm guessing that this Form1 instance is creating and displaying the Form2 instance in the first place. In that case, Form2 should be raising an event that Form1 can handle and then call its own method itself. If this is happening when Form2 closes after calling ShowDialog, you don't even need that. All you'd need would be a property in Form2.

Comment: I agree with jmcilhinney, I think it would be good for you to set a breakpoint and step through your code. Here's a video on how to do that: https://youtu.be/EceKLMxzE_8?si=dTlCoFR7RTImFfgH

Comment: @jmcilhinney Using an EventHandler fixed the issue for me. Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: If you have solved your own issue, you should post an answer to your question that demonstrates that solution. SO is not just a place to get help yourself but also to help others with the same problem. It may also be that others can help you improve the solution if it is not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how I accomplished the issue I was having. Instead of using form1.something = value I used an eventhandler. Like this:

```
' Form1.vb
Public Class Form1
    ' Declare an instance of Form2
    Private WithEvents form2 As Form2

    Private Sub btnOpenForm2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenForm2.Click
        ' Create an instance of Form2
        form2 = New Form2()

        ' Show Form2 as a dialog
        form2.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    ' Event handler for the event raised in Form2
    Private Sub Form2ValueEntered(value As String) Handles form2.ValueEntered
        ' Update the text on Form1 with the value entered in Form2
        lblForm1.Text = "Value entered in Form2: " & value
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then on Form 2:

```
    ' Form2.vb
Public Class Form2
    ' Define an event that will be raised when a value is entered
    Public Event ValueEntered As Action(Of String)

    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        ' Get the value entered by the user
        Dim enteredValue As String = txtValue.Text

        ' Raise the event and pass the entered value
        RaiseEvent ValueEntered(enteredValue)

        ' Close Form2
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

So when you enter a value on Form2 and click Submit, the value in the textbox will be sent to the Form1 label.

Comment: That certainly implements the appropriate principles. Personally, I would stick more closely to the existing conventions for events, so the event would be type `EventHandler` and then the data would be retrieved from a property, or else it would be type `EventHandler(Of TEventArgs)`, where `TEventArgs` is some type of your own that inherits `EventArgs` and adds a property for the data. See [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html) for more info.

Comment: In this case, you didn't actually need the event at all. You are calling `ShowDialog` so the first form can simply get the data from the second form when that returns. Instead of raising the event, simply set a property. In the first form, just get that property value after `ShowDialog` returns. No need to raise or handle an event. It's much like you would get the `FileName` property after showing an `OpenFileDialog` or `SaveFileDialog`. If you need to distinguish between the user clickong `OK` or not, set the `DialogResult` instead of calling close, then check what `ShowDialog` returns.